# Whats the most efficient way to solve an equation numericaly (because it has no analitical solution)

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

So, I think the problem that Im having is simple but, still, Im not sure on how to do it. I have an equation with no analitical solution:

$a_1 \sin \left(2 \theta \right)+a_2 \sin \left(2 \phi\right)+a_3 \cos \left(2 \theta\right)+a_4 \cos \left(2 \phi\right)=a_5$

where $a_i$ are just numbers which are not relevant to the discussion. This equation has numerical solutions, what I need is a list $\{\theta,\phi\}$ that satisfy this equation. What would be the best way to do this? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions, aren't there? (Even over the finite interval $[0, \pi]$ -- one equation, two unknowns.)

Comment: Yes, that's right!

Comment: So what sort of list do you want?  (A complete list of numbers is impossible.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What have you tried so far?

You can use `Solve` to solve for `θ`.

```
Solve[a1 Sin[2θ] + a2 Sin[2ϕ] + a3 Cos[2θ] + a4 Cos[2ϕ] == a5, θ] /. _C -> 0
```

Since your equation have periods `π`, you can just let `ϕ` run between `0` and `π`, and add arbitrary multiples of `π` to the solutions.

### Another way

You can plot it using `ContourPlot`. I used bounds `0 < θ < π` and `0 < ϕ < π` since those are the periods.

```
With[{a1 = 1, a2 = 2, a3 = 2, a4 = 3, a5 = 4},
  ContourPlot[a1 Sin[2θ] + a2 Sin[2ϕ] + a3 Cos[2θ] + a4 Cos[2ϕ] == a5, {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, π}]
]
```

[image]

You can extract the points it found too.

```
With[{a1 = 1, a2 = 2, a3 = 2, a4 = 3, a5 = 4},
  Cases[
    ContourPlot[a1 Sin[2θ] + a2 Sin[2ϕ] + a3 Cos[2θ] + a4 Cos[2ϕ] == a5, {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, π}],
  {_Real, _Real}, Infinity]
]

(* {{0.785398,0.},{0.835369,0.0560999},{0.838041,0.0595571},
   {0.841498,0.0646637},{0.874146,0.1122},{0.8826,0.127197},
   {0.897598,0.158172},{0.902625,0.1683}, <<212>>, 
   {0.113599,2.91579},{0.1122,2.91602},{0.111224,2.91622},
   {0.106423,2.91719},{0.0560999,2.92813},{0.0413688,2.93192},
   {0.0206391,2.93783},{0.,2.94422}} *)
```

You can find more points this way by increasing `MaxRecursion`.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed! Greatly appreciated!